# ReflectionTypeLoadException exception when used with Asp.Net Core in-memory TestServer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, integration-testing, in-memory-database

We have been experiencing a really intermittent issue within our component tests which can be found just below:

- System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException : Unable to load one or more of the requested types.

This is a well-rounded example of what's happening that was just shut down by the automapper devs: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2973

Im not entirely sure what's causing this but we have just made a big change to in-memory db's so as people are claiming this is the route, because of this I wouldn't be surprised if that's the problem. If you have had any experience with this or can spot something wrong with the snippets below that would be awesome as I'm lost on this one.

The stack trace can be found below that describes the error that's produced.

Create some exception middleware to catch the issue (code can be seen below) as it only occurs on the test server side of things and from researching into this everyone facing this issue was using in-memory DB's.

**TEST SETUP**

```cs
   public class PermissiveTestServerFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
   {
       protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
       {
           builder.UseContentRoot(".");
           base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
       }

       protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
       {
           var serviceProjectPath = Path.Combine(GetSolutionFolder(), "src", "Zupa.Products.ProductsService");

           return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
               .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(serviceProjectPath)
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
               .Build())
               .Configure(builder => builder.UseMiddleware<LoaderExceptionHandler>())
               .UseEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Development)
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
               {
                   services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                   {
                       options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Permissive Scheme";
                       options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Permissive Scheme";
                   }).AddTestAuthentication(o => { });

                   services.AddScoped<DbContextOptions<TradingDbContext>>(provider =>
                   {
                       var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TradingDbContext>(
                               new DbContextOptions<TradingDbContext>(
                                   new Dictionary<Type, IDbContextOptionsExtension>()));

                       builder.UseApplicationServiceProvider(provider);

                       builder.UseSqlServer(TestConstants.SQLConnectionString);

                       return builder.Options;
                   });

                   services.AddTestCosmosClient<ProductEntity>();
                   services.AddTestCosmosClient<ProductCategoryEntity>();
                   services.AddTestCosmosClient<InternalPriceListEntity>();
                   services.AddTestCosmosClient<PurchasePricesEntity>(config =>
                   {
                       config.IdPropertyName = nameof(PurchasePricesEntity.PurchaserId);
                   });

                   services.AddSingleton<ICosmosClient<BrandEntity>>(_ =>
                       new TestCosmosClient<BrandEntity>(config =>
                       {
                           config.IdPropertyName = nameof(BrandEntity.Name);
                       }));

                   services.AddTransient<IProductsRepository>(provider =>
                       new ProductsRepository(
                           provider.GetRequiredService<ICosmosClient<ProductEntity>>(),
                           provider.GetRequiredService<IMapper>()));

                   services.AddTransient<IProductCategoriesRepository>(provider =>
                       new ProductCategoriesRepository(
                           provider.GetRequiredService<ICosmosClient<ProductCategoryEntity>>(),
                           provider.GetRequiredService<IMapper>(),
                           provider.GetRequiredService<IProductsRepository>()));

                   services.AddTransient<IBrandsRepository>(provider =>
                      new BrandsRepository(
                          provider.GetRequiredService<ICosmosClient<BrandEntity>>(),
                          provider.GetRequiredService<IMapper>(),
                          provider.GetRequiredService<ITelemetryTracker>()));

                   services.AddTransient<ITradingUnitOfWork>(provider =>
                   {
                       var tradingDbContext = provider.GetRequiredService<ITradingDbContextFactory>();
                       var mapper = provider.GetRequiredService<IMapper>();
                       var priceListReadRepository = provider.GetRequiredService<IPriceListReadRepository>();
                       var dbExceptionInterpreter = provider.GetRequiredService<IDbExceptionInterpreter>();

                       return
                           new TradingUnitOfWorkSchemaGenerator(
                               new TradingUnitOfWork(
                                   tradingDbContext,
                                   mapper,
                                   priceListReadRepository,
                                   dbExceptionInterpreter
                               ),
                               tradingDbContext
                           );
                   });

                   services.Configure<DefaultDataSettings>(config =>
                   {
                       config.ProductCategories = DefaultData.ProductCategories;
                       config.BrandNames = DefaultData.BrandNames;
                   });

                   services.Configure<TableStorageSettings>(config =>
                   {
                       config.ConnectionString = TestConstants.TableStorageConnectionString;
                       config.TableName = TestConstants.TableStorageTableName;
                   });
               });
       }

       private static string GetSolutionFolder()
       {
           var folder = new DirectoryInfo(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath);

           while (folder != null && !folder.GetFiles("*.sln").Any())
               folder = folder.Parent;

           if (folder == null)
               throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find solution folder for the current project");

           return folder.FullName;
       }
   }
```

**LoaderExceptionHandler**

```cs
public class LoaderExceptionHandler
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _delegate;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public LoaderExceptionHandler(RequestDelegate requestDelegate, ILogger<LoaderExceptionHandler> logger)
        {
            _delegate = requestDelegate;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _delegate(context);
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
            {
                foreach (Exception ex in e.LoaderExceptions)
                {
                    _logger.LogCritical(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException : Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
[11:12:03][Step 1/1] Could not load type 'Castle.Proxies.IOrganisationsServiceProxyProxy' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
[11:12:03][Step 1/1] Could not load type 'Castle.Proxies.Invocations.IOrganisationsServiceProxy_GetOrganisationChildrenAsync' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
[11:12:03][Step 1/1] Stack Trace:
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.ToArray()
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at AutoMapper.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapperClasses(IServiceCollection services, Action`2 configAction, IEnumerable`1 assembliesToScan) in C:\projects\automapper-extensions-microsoft-dependencyinjectio\src\AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection\ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:line 72
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at Zupa.Products.ProductsService.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\BuildAgent_v10\work\89160412962c53ca\src\Zupa.Products.ProductsService\Startup.cs:line 138
[11:12:03][Step 1/1] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer..ctor(IWebHostBuilder builder, IFeatureCollection featureCollection)
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateServer(IWebHostBuilder builder)
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer()
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient(WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions options)
[11:12:03][Step 1/1]    at Zupa.Products.ProductsService.ComponentTests.PriceListV2Tests.EditPriceList_OrganisationIdEmpty_ReturnsBadRequest() in C:\BuildAgent_v10\work\89160412962c53ca\test\Zupa.Products.ProductsService.ComponentTests\PriceListV2Tests.cs:line 481
[11:12:03][Step 1/1] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core